# How do I eliminate the space between my header and section title?

Tags: header-footer, section-titles

I'm currently trying to make a system where I can organize lecture notes effectively in a readable fashion - however, I've ran into some trouble in that I can't seem to get rid of the egregious amount of whitespace nested between my headers and section titles. Can someone find out how to get rid of this space for me?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{Number Theory Part 1}
\rhead{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\def\thesection{Day \arabic{section}:}
\def\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\normalfont\bfseries\raggedright}{\hspace{0mm}\thesection}{0.5em}{} %change 0.5em to your needs

\begin{document}
\section{Test Message}
\subsection{Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Do you mean `\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}`?

Comment: Sorry but... I don't understand what you mean. Can you elaborate? I'm new to LaTeX, just using this to organize some lecture notes :D

Nevermind, I figured out what you meant. it works great! Tysm.

Comment: The tag `\headsep` controls the white space between `running head` and the `text`. Hope I'm clear, please let me know if you need further explanation....

Comment: I got help already, but thanks for replying to my question anyways <3

Comment: Glad to hear that your problem got solved, note that you can answer your own question here, so that it will help to some other guy....

Answer (score 0):

`\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}` works just fine! Thanks to MadyYuvi. :)